# Exception logging tools in .Net

Tags: .net, devtools

I'm looking for a good tool that will give me a detailed analysis of exception in production releases.

I know of EurekaLog and I saw once an add for a software with a frog or something similar in it's name, searched it in Google without any results.

Does anyone have recomandations ?

My main goal of course is to extract the maximum amount of useful information when a crash occurs in production.

Also, maybe a bit off topic, something similar for dead-lock detection.

Comment: You may want to be specific if you want something that you can load that will automatically log uncaught exceptions, or a log tool where you log specifically what you want. You say exceptions in production which makes me think you want the former, but you dont specify.

Answer (score 5):

[Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure if you are looking for a Winforms or ASP.NET solution here. But for ASP.NET I am using Elmah (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

Answer (score 0):

We use Enterprise Library Logging Application block.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd139916.aspx

You determine how much is logged, through configuration and where you place the logging statements. It also allows you to change the amount of information that is logged without stopping the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want freedom of choice without creating a strong dependency on a specific logging framework (Log4Net, nLog, EntLib) you could take a look at the Common.Logging library. It basically abstracts away the implementation of the logger, exposing only a common interface to all available logging blocks.

See:

http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/

Disclaimer:
I haven't used it myself (yet), but I do intend to try it out sometime soon. The idea of not being tied to a specific logger appeals to me, as I like to stick to one log library per project. Imagine building a project which uses nLog for logging, but then you add NHibernate. NH uses Log4Net, so now we've got TWO logging libraries in our dependencies ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers but it's not the direction I was looking for. I'm more interested in the *exception* reports of unexpected errors / crashes, and the maximum amount of data that can be extracted to understand why it happened, such as, all threads stack traces, last actions (clicks) the user has made, etc.

The logging frameworks are only as valuable as the stuff I write in.